# Is there any way to read a text file in javascript beside using ActiveX?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

Given all the files (html file, text files, etc) are on the web,
is there any way to read text file and print them in a textarea beside using ActiveX?

I've tried like this, but it didn't reach the goal:

```
function getSelectedItem(){
   var client = new XMLHttpRequest();

   if(document.codeForm.dropList.value == "foo")
      client.open('GET', 'foo.txt');
   else if(document.codeForm.dropList.value == "bar")
      client.open('GET', 'bar.txt');
   client.onreadystatechange = function() {
      //This actually displays the message in the file
      alert(client.responseText);

      //But this doesn't. This just displays "undefined"
//    document.codeForm.source.value = client.reponseText;
   }
   client.send();
}
```

Since I could actually display alert message with the file context, I believe there would be some way to do this.
(Actually the contents of files seem to come into "client.reponseText",
 but it's data type is DOMstring, not just String.)

Any advice would be very appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use jQuery. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

```
$.get("http://www.whatever.com/foo.txt", null, function(response){
    $("#theTextArea").val(response); // where theTextArea is the ID of the textarea you want to put the data into.
});
```

Comment: @Mike Ruhlin- wat if the txt and html file are both there locally on system

Answer (score 0):

try this instead

```
document.codeForm.source.innerValue = client.reponseText;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("source").innerHtml = client.responseText;
```

or

```
document.getElementById("source").innerText = client.responseText;
```

your textarea will need an id attribute to use the last two methods

Comment: I've just tried but it doesn't give any change in the textarea.

Comment: they still led "undefined". I fixed the problem by using jQuery anyway. Thank you.